# Update DataGrid in WPF from another window

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid control on a window called MainWindow. From MainWindow i open another window called NewCustomerWindow using the following code on a button click.

```
NewCustomerWindow newCustomerWindow = new NewCustomerWindow();
newCustomerWindow.ShowDialog();
```

In the NewCustomerWindow i have a form with textboxes where someone can enter information about a customer and then these information are saved into a database. After i save these information i want to update the DataGrid in the MainWindow so i use the following code

```
var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows
                .OfType<MainWindow>()
                .FirstOrDefault(window => window is MainWindow);

mainWindow.customersGrid.Items.Add(new 
            {
                CustomerID = txtCustomerID.Text,
                CompanyName = txtCompanyName.Text,
                ContactName = txtContactName.Text,
                ContactTitle = txtContactTitle.Text,
                Address = txtAddress.Text,
                City = txtCity.Text,
                Region = txtRegion.Text,
                PostalCode = txtPostalCode.Text,
                Country = txtCountry.Text,
                Phone = txtPhone.Text,
                Fax = txtFax.Text
            });
```

The above code returns the following error: **"Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."**

customersGrid is the name of the DataGrid in MainWindow and its structure is as follows.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="8,29,8,8" Name="customersGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Loaded="customersGrid_Loaded">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding CustomerID}" Header="Κωδικός Πελάτη"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding CompanyName}" Header="Όνομα Εταιρίας"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding ContactName}" Header="Όνομα Επαφής"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding ContactTitle}" Header="Τίτλος Επαφής"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Address}" Header="Διεύθυνση"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding City}" Header="Πόλη"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Region}" Header="Περιοχή"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding PostalCode}" Header="Ταχυδρομικός Κώδικας"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Country}" Header="Χώρα"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Phone}" Header="Τηλέφωνο"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Fax}" Header="Fax"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I suppose that a solution is to set the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid again with all the data but this is not a good choice because the customers data is coming from a wcf service which brings a lot of records. So, what is a good solution to this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should bind your dataGrid to some viewmodels depentency property and update the property instead of looking for the main window

Comment: Hello @makc. Could you please provide some further information about your suggestion because i am not familiar with that. Thank you.

Comment: Whats your DataGrid's/Window's DataContext?

Comment: Currently in my code i set the ItemsSource not the DataContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you set your `MainWindow.DataContext = MainViewModel.Instance` 
(your choice to create it a singleton or not)

your MainViewModel class should have an observableCollection dependency property lets call it Customers. 
you bind your DataGrid to to Customers

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" />
```

so when you want to update the datagrid you just update Customers (for example from NewCustomerWindow) and the dataGrid will automatically be updated

here are nice examples:

[A-Practical-Quick-start-Tutorial-on-MVVM-in-WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81484/A-Practical-Quick-start-Tutorial-on-MVVM-in-WPF)

[DataGrid Tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation and the links