# How to update dataGrid in WPF from another window without using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf

I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195901/update-datagrid-in-wpf-from-another-window) to find the answer of my question. but i want to know, Is there a way that we don't have to use MVVM. At first, Let me ask my question!! I have a DataGrid control on a window called `MainWindow`. From `MainWindow` i open another window called `NewWindow` . in `NewWindow` i have some textbox and a button. In the `NewWindow` someone can enter information about a customer and then these information are saved into a database, so i use the following code in follow of button in `NewWindow`.

```
var Que = (from P in FaceDB.tblUsers where P.UserId == mytxtbox1.Text.ToString() select P).SingleOrDefault();

                Que.Pass = mytxtbox2.Text.ToString();
                FaceDB.SaveChanges();
```

After i save these information i want to update the DataGrid in the MainWindow. i try with following codes but none of them didn't work:

```
Que.Pass = mytxtbox2.Text.ToString();
FaceDB.SaveChanges();
MainPage MPWin = new MainPage();
MPWin.mydatagridt.UpdateLayout();
```

OR:

```
MPWin.mydatagrid.Items.Refresh();
```

OR:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(mydatagrid.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

One can directly set the data in code for the `DataGrid` using its `ItemsSource`, here is a modification of your example:

```
Que.Pass = mytxtbox2.Text.ToString();
FaceDB.SaveChanges();

MainPage MPWin = new MainPage();

MPWin.mydatagridt.ItemsSource = Que.ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, but i have this error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'FaceApp.FaceDBEntities.tblUser' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'`  anyway i try with following code but it doesn't work too :  `var q= from b in FaceDB.tblUsers
                                                                  select b;
                    MPWin.mydatagrid.ItemsSource = null;
                    MPWin.mydatagrid.ItemsSource = q.ToList();
                    MPWin.mydatagrid.Items.Refresh();`

Comment: @Saeid one needs to provide a hard list to be used which one should `ToList()` as mentioned. Check the data in the debugger, does it exist properly and does the data grid generate the columns automatically? You need to provide the XAML.